# Mule ESB application deployed on JBoss: mapped-name is required for org.apache.cxf.binding.BindingFactoryManagerImpl

Tags: jboss5.x, mule, esb

I'm trying to deploy Mule ESB application on JBoss (5.1.0.GA), as .war file. 
When I start JBoss, I'm getting followiong error:

```
13:37:06,952 ERROR [StandardContext] Context [/OMS] startup failed due to previous errors
java.lang.RuntimeException: mapped-name is required for     org.apache.cxf.binding.BindingFactoryManagerImpl/bus of deployment OMS.war
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.injection.WebResourceHandler.loadXmlResourceEnvRefs    (WebResourceHandler.java:287)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.injection.WebResourceHandler.loadXml(WebResourceHandler.java:325)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.processMetadata(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:550)
```

Here is jboss-classloading.xml

```
<classloading xmlns="urn:jboss:classloading:1.0"
 name="OMS.war"
 domain="OMS"
 export-all="NON_EMPTY"
 import-all="false">
</classloading>
```

jboss-web.xml

```
<jboss-web>
<class-loading>
    <loader-repository>
     <loader-repository-config>  
            java2ParentDelegation=false  
         </loader-repository-config>  
</loader-repository>
  </class-loading>
 </jboss-web>
```

And web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" 
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
   <context-param>
       <param-name>org.mule.config</param-name>
   <param-value>_includes.xml,_subflows.xml,monitor_flow.xml,claim_flow.xml,orders_flows.xml,parcel_flow.xml,create_claim_flow.xml,request_flows.xml,retry_flow.xml,inbound_parcel_flow.xml,server_status_flow.xml,insurance_policy_flow.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>

   <listener>
       <listener-class>org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
</web-app>
```

These 3 xml files are under WEB-INF. All .jar files are under WEB-INF/lib

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.